# What to use for Xamarin?

Tags: android, css, ios, xamarin, styling

I was wondering what should I use to style my app. I saw that some people use CSS. The question is, is it compatible and should I start using CSS? or if there's a different better language to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many controls you can use to style your app, refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/.

If you want more functions or appearence which forms can't provide, you can use custom renderer to achieve native control.refer to this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Although, you should get familiar with **XMAL** first, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/